# Can't scroll to anchor

Tags: html, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, anchor

I want to create periodic table that shows you some additional info after clicking element symbol. I have used the example found on codepen: https://codepen.io/ankit567/pen/wxbYXE, and I have managed to get it working with collapsible divs at the bottom of page. Unfortunately my knowledge is not allowing me to overcome my latest problem. I can't get the page to scroll to just opened collapsible.

Here you can find my current work:
https://codepen.io/zfkibuj/pen/RwpGWBL

I would be extremely grateful if you could help me finding solution.

I would like the page to scroll to

```
<h1 id="tresc">Wzorce, odczynniki, roztwory pomocnicze do oznaczania</h1>
```

after clicking on:

```
<div class="element other-nonmetal c1 r1">
        <div data-toggle="collapse" href="#h" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="h">
          <input class="activate" name="elements" type="radio" />
          <input class="deactivate" name="elements" type="radio" />
          <div class="square">
            <div class="atomic-number">1</div>
            <div class="label">
              <div class="symbol">H</div>
              <div class="name">Wodór</div>
            </div>
            <div class="atomic-mass">1.008</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Perhaps the solution is really easy, but I have only some basic experience with Wordpress websites. This is my biggest project so far :)

So far I have found this:

```
$('#h').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
  this.scrollIntoView();
});
```

To work pretty well, but I don't know how to make it work with other id's like #he, #li, #be and so on...

Comment: The standard solution is to use a common class on all your elements and apply the event handler to that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I solved it by adding

onClick="document.getElementById('tresc').scrollIntoView();"

to

```
<div data-toggle="collapse" href="#h" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="h">
```

with final solution as follows:

```
<div data-toggle="collapse" href="#be" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="be" onClick="document.getElementById('tresc').scrollIntoView();">
```